# "Type '() => string[]' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 25 more" error occurs in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to set the config file by getting the value of an environment variable.
But I'm getting delayed with the following error:

> Type '() => string[]' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 25 more.

```
// env set
// MQTT_BROKER_TOPIC=/test/stack/overflow/kbg, /test/stack/overflow/kbg22

// interface
export interface BrokerInfo {
  host: string;
  port: number;
  topic: string[];
};

// topic return data
const envBrokerParse = (): string[] => {
  let result:string[] = [];
  const envBrokerTopic: string|undefined = process.env.MQTT_BROKER_TOPIC;

  if (!envBrokerTopic) { result = envBrokerTopic.split(','); }
  if (result.length === 0) { result = ['/test/stack/overflow/kbg']; }

  return result;
}

/**
 * mqtt broker info
 */
export const mqttBrokerInfo: Array<BrokerInfo> = [
  {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 1883,
    topic: envBrokerParse, // type error
  },
];
```

An attempt was made to put the return value of "envBrokerParse" in a "topic" but an error occurred.
I think "envBrokerParse" must return a string[] type.
But I don't know why this error occurs. What is the reason?

Comment: if(!envBrokerTopic) means that if its undefined, split it. which result in the error cannot read property "split" of undefined. which i think is stopping it from inferring all paths return string[]

Comment: @ShanonJackson Thank you so much for the answer. As you said, I tried changing if(!envBrokerTopic) to if (envBrokerTopic === undefined) but I still get the same error.

Comment: Sorry its because you need envBrokerParse() to execute the function, the function by itself is not assignable to string[] untill its executed; misunderstood the error

Comment: @ShanonJackson 
Thank you for writing the example code. If you add the mqttBrokerInfo variable written above to your code, you will get the same error.

Comment: Miss read, execute the function error disappears. Left a answer

Comment: @ShanonJackson Oh my... 
I'm really stupid Thank you very much for your kindly response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want

```
export const mqttBrokerInfo: Array<BrokerInfo> = [
  {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 1883,
    topic: envBrokerParse(), // no type error  what you want is envBrokerParse()
  },
];
```